# Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery UI modal in mvc4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, razor, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to include both Twitter Bootstrap layout and jQuery UI scripts. First part, including scripts from jQuery UI for modal and datepicker worked fine on the generic MVC4 template view.

Today I installed the Twitter view and rendering the same body within twitter bootstrap view doesn't show the datepicker and the modal, plus I am getting these js errors:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'
```

Is it possible to combine jQuery UI parts in twitter bootstrap view? This is the view I have from Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
      <script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="../../Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <!-- Le styles -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Content/icons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="~/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="~/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="~/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="~/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body" class="container">
     @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>    

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

  </body>
</html>
```

And the generic view is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Document", "Document", "Home")</li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: never mind, the script bundle at the bottom was making the mess, I removed that and it works great now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, the script bundle at the bottom was making the mess, I removed that and it works great now. Sorry.